# Python won't work for some strange reason

Tags: command-line, python3, error-handling, pycharm

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 dual boot and Python 3.6.8, so I guess the trouble began from there. I was trying to run a file in PyCharm when it threw this error:

`/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'temp.py' (AttributeError: module 'temp' has no attribute '__path__')`

Now, I don't really know much about PyCharm, so I thought it'd be easier to save time and open the file on terminal, except that the terminal threw the same error. I then tried just straight up writing my code on the terminal, so I opened python on terminal and checked. It worked fine till `sys.version`, but as soon as I typed `import numpy`, it gave me this:

```
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/_globals.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/_globals.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/_globals.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'numpy._globals' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41ebc3b400>
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/__config__.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/__config__.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'numpy.__config__' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41ebc3b780>
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/version.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/version.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__pycache__/version.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'numpy.version' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41ebc3b908>
...
...
...
import 'gc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'numpy.testing._private.utils' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41e0646940>
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/__pycache__/decorators.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/decorators.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/__pycache__/decorators.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'numpy.testing._private.decorators' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41e05d9940>
# /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/__pycache__/nosetester.cpython-36.pyc matches /home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/nosetester.py
# code object from '/home/vihangbodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/__pycache__/nosetester.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'numpy.testing._private.nosetester' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41e05ea550>
import 'numpy.testing' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41e06bd3c8>
import 'numpy' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f41ef4faa20>
>>>
```

The full terminal output is [here](https://gist.github.com/Vihangbodh/5381dd84f7529bef1ed18d88b1cefcaa) (it's bigger than the 30,000 character limit here), and that really looks like some trouble. What exactly did I mess up there? And how can it be fixed, if it can be at all?

**EDIT:** Here is the ouput of `apt policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable/main i386 Packages
     release o=Vivaldi Technologies,a=stable,l=Official Vivaldi package repository,c=main,b=i386
     origin repo.vivaldi.com
 500 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Vivaldi Technologies,a=stable,l=Official Vivaldi package repository,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.vivaldi.com
 500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise/steam i386 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=precise,l=Steam,c=steam,b=i386
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise/steam amd64 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=precise,l=Steam,c=steam,b=amd64
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main i386 Packages
     release v=1,o=packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack,a=jessie,n=jessie,l=slack,c=main,b=i386
     origin packagecloud.io
 500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1,o=packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack,a=jessie,n=jessie,l=slack,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packagecloud.io
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=***** The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=***** The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release o=mongodb,a=bionic,n=bionic/mongodb-org,l=mongodb,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin repo.mongodb.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-linrunner-tlp,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=TLP,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-linrunner-tlp,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=TLP,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-inkscape.dev-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Inkscape Stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-inkscape.dev-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Inkscape Stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-apt-fast-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=apt-fast stable PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-apt-fast-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=apt-fast stable PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=bionic,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: The version of Python that shipped with 18.04 is 3.6.5, upgraded to 3.6.7. If you installed some non-Ubuntu 3.6.8, I would start by reverting back to the Ubuntu version.

Comment: @user535733 it got updated automatically, and I have been using the same version for at least months now. (side note: I deleted my /var/cache right after starting my system (bad practice, I know, but nothing else helps me clear space)...could that be related?)

Comment: Lots of things "could" be. You must systematically rule out the constellation of possible causes and narrow to what's likely. "It got updated automatically" implies that you have non-Ubuntu sources adding poorly-tested packages that break your system. That's a common cause of breakage...and you are complaining about breakage.

Comment: @user535733 no I meant it got updated to 3.6.8 by `apt-get update`. I agree on narrowing down part, but I have no idea where to start...

Comment: apt-get uses ALL enabled sources, including non-Ubuntu sources...which is what it seemed to do.

Comment: You could edit to show the output of 'apt policy' on whatever the python package is. That would tell where it came from.

Comment: @user535733 even if it does, why would the problem only show up right now? I have not updated Ubuntu in more than a week, but never stopped using Python...so why only now? This is where I am getting confused about this :/

Comment: @OrganicMarble done :)